# Dynamic Tables & Continuous queries in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I am creating a flink job, that needs Dynamic Tables with continuous queries,I found the concept [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/table/streaming.html) but did not find any good example program to try it on.
Can someone help me in this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for examples that use SQL, I would suggest either the [Flink SQL Training](https://github.com/ververica/sql-training/) or the [Flink SQL Demo](https://github.com/fhueske/flink-sql-demo) shown in [Flink SQL in 2020: Time to show off! - Fabian Hueske & Timo Walther](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnCkwIp_614).

If you prefer the Table API, there's a [tutorial in the docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/try-flink/table_api.html).